# Collective Being

Tags: ontology, existence, self

If, as a Collective of embodied selves (eSelves) we voted for ideas instead of individual eSelves - the objective being to construct a Reality that resonates with Existence itself - what would that process look like?

Answer (score 1):

Hannah Arendt pointed that the body political - that is people considered as a polity - must be oriented around an ideology; since the word 'ideology' carries with it a hint of opprobrium since the clash of ideologies during the long Cold War, it might be better merely to say they need to be organised around ideas/policies.

The problem then is to come up with an idea or policy that the many can advocate for.

Comment: I agree. A Vision is what is needed. If agreed to, then voting would be for ideas, like pieces of the Vision puzzle.